# How do I graph a cylinder within a sphere with an app or software?

Tags: math-software, spheres, solid-geometry

I Have tried a lot of different ways but for some reason my program isn't registering the information that I am putting in. I am doing this for my *Calculus III* class.

When I put in the information for the given shapes they are not coming out as expected.

Comment: what program are you using?

Comment: My apologize i am using, graphing calculator 3d, well was using it untill my free version apparently expired. hopefully i will be able to use it again soon

Comment: which app though

Comment: If your free version is expired, what alternatives are you using right now? Besides, there's a chance that you'll never be able to use it again for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to plot cylinder within sphere in Graphing Calculator 3D:

1. Type the sphere equation. For example: x^2+y^2+z^2=3^2
2. Type the cylinder equation. For example: x^2+y^2=2^2
3. Calculate the height of the cylinder needed to ensure the cylinder does not stick out of the sphere. The height is generally calculated by this formula: R^2=r^2+(h/2)^2
4. Solve the above for h. Once you know the value of h, change the default z range of cylinder from (-Infinity, +Infinity) to (-h/2, +h/2). In this example the range would be (-2.23, +2.23)

Here is the result after making the sphere transparent:

[image]